# Using Map-Reduce framework for calculating distances in a large graph

Tags: graph

I have a large (un-directed and un-weighted) graph and I'm interested in calculating the shortest paths (BFS) between all of the 4-touples in the graph. Trivial way takes a complexity of n^4.

Now, suppose that I have more than one core dedicated for this task.

Is there an intelligent way to use Map-Reduce for my task? i.e. splitting this task into smaller independent task? Is there a framework that will allow me splitting the problem into smaller ones and performing calculation in parallel.

Thanks.

Comment: Problems with your question: framework for what language and platform?  what have you found or tried before asking here?

Comment: I prefer C++/Python on windows. But if you have good suggestions for other platforms, I'll consider them.